# Count Occurances of value in 2 columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a simple job to do in PowerBi but for some reason I can not get my head around it.

I have projects table - in this table we have "date of start" and "date of end". What I am after is a smaller table with "Year & Quarter" first column and a count of projects started and count of project ended in that "Year & Quarter".

| Project Number | Started | Ended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xxxx23 | 2019-01 | 2019-03 |
| xxxx24 | 2019-03 | 2020-01 |
| xxxx25 | 2019-03 | 2020-02 |

what I am after is something like below:

| Year & Quarter | Project Started | Project Ended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-03 | 2 | 1 |
| 2019-04 | 0 | 0 |

When doing the calculations, I am getting wrong counts. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION to create a new table.  You can use the original table twice but with different columns.

```
NewTable = 
    UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS( Projects,
                        "date",Projects[started],
                        "project",Projects[project],
                        "Started",1,
                        "Ended",0
                    )
        ,
        SELECTCOLUMNS( Projects,
                        "date",Projects[ended],
                        "project",Projects[project],
                        "Started",0,
                        "Ended",1
                    )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Calendar Table, you can achieve the ask by doing following two ways

#1

```
newTable = 
VAR _1 =
    SUMMARIZE ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Yr & Qt] )
VAR _2 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            _1,
            "Project Started",
                COUNTX (
                    FILTER ( Projects, Projects[started] = EARLIER ( [Yr & Qt] ) ),
                    [started]
                )
        ),
        "Project Ended", COUNTX ( FILTER ( Projects, Projects[ended] = EARLIER ( [Yr & Qt] ) ), [ended] )
    )
RETURN
    _2
```

#2

```
Table 2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Yr & Qt] ),
        "Project Start Count",
            CALCULATE (
                CALCULATE (
                    COUNTX ( Projects, Projects[started] ),
                    TREATAS ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Yr & Qt] ), Projects[started] )
                )
            )
    ),
    "Project End Count",
        CALCULATE (
            CALCULATE (
                COUNTX ( Projects, Projects[ended] ),
                TREATAS ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Calendar', 'Calendar'[Yr & Qt] ), Projects[ended] )
            )
        )
)
```

results in following

[image: SOlution]

The solution has minimum dependency to a Calendar tbl with a column like `Yr & Qt` as following

[image: Solution]